# Specifing semver operator for npm install --save

Tags: node.js, npm, semantic-versioning

By default `npm install --save` uses `^` as the semver operator. I know that this default can be changed using setting the [`save-prefix`](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#save-prefix) config. But since I want to specify `~` for dependencies and `^` for devDependencies, I don't want to change the config. Is there a way to specify the `~` operator with the `--save` command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:
`npm install <package> --save --save-prefix='<prefix>'`

For example: `npm install gulp --save --save-prefix='~'`

Comment: Thanks. On Windows, I had to use double-quotes instead of single quotes around "~". It works without the quotes too.